# Transforming an eclipse pde project into a bndtools project

Tags: java, osgi, eclipse-pde, bnd, bndtools

I'm trying to transform an old pde project into a new bndtools project and I ran into some issues doing so.
I've tried to use the CLI bnd to transform it according to [this documentation](https://github.com/bndtools/bnd/blob/master/docs/_commands/eclipse-pde.md) but for some reason it is not doing what I expected and throws me the error

```
000: Unnecessary arguments [pde, -w, test_wp/, -c, -i, control.bnd]
```

I'm having the version **4.1.0.201810181252** of bnd on my macOS system.

My working directory looks as follows:

[image]

And the command I used was this one:

```
bnd eclipse pde -w test_wp/ -c -i control.bnd
```

Even by trying to only use **bnd eclipse pde** the resulting error looked like this:

[image]

I hope one of you can hint me in the right direction.

Comment: This is an experimental version of bnd that is not part of the main line. It was developed for QIvicon. I still need to merge it in master :-( You can contact me privately if you you're serious about porting pde projects and I can give you a copy.

Comment: That copy is not up to date. Again, send me a mail and we work something out. This should not be on Stackoverflow yet imho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use a feature which is not yet public available.
I will ask author (Peter Kriens) if I can share the version, or when this feature will be available in bnd.